# Why does chrome not render flexbox positioning for an embedded twitter timeline?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter, flexbox

Can anyone shed light on why Chrome (Version 78.0.3904.97) does not respect flexbox css for centering a Twitter timeline in a web page?

Using the Twitter generated code for embedding a Twitter timeline into a web page I have found that trying to center the timeline is proving impossible in Chrome. It works fine in Safari.

[Safari screenshot showing the Twitter timeline centered in the twt class div](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gD12i.png)
[Chrome screenshot showing the Twitter timeline left-aligned in the twt class div](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pv75d.png)

```
/* html snippet */

<div class="twt">

   <a class="twitter-timeline" data-width="640" data-height="860" href="https://twitter.com/PremierLake?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw">Tweets by PremierLake</a> 
    <script async src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>

</div>

/* flexbox css */

.twt {
  display: flex; 
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: stretch;
  width: 100%;
  height: 860px;
}
```

Notes:
I have tried non-flexbox traditional positioning. I do not want to use absolute positioning as the div structure needs to flow with the surrounding elements on the page.
I have trawled the Twitter dev notes and they offer no way to center a timeline.
This is NOT to same as an  encased single tweet, which can be centered.
The Twitter timeline is a collection of tweets from a single Twitter feed.

Comment: Have you tried using your browser dev tools to inspect the element and applied styles?

Comment: It's working fine on both Safari and chrome. If you are still troubling then please explain bit more with your code and will check.

Answer (score 0):

I don't get an answer for it, but I tried your code. it worked fine for me!
[image: screenshot for both safari and chrome]

try to inspect the element in chrome, and see what styles were actually applied to it.

I didn't change your code except that I highlighted the background.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
      /* flexbox css */

      .twt {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
        align-content: stretch;
        width: 100%;
        height: 860px;
        background: yellow;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>blalbalbalb</h1>
    <div class="twt">
      <a
        class="twitter-timeline"
        data-width="640"
        data-height="860"
        href="https://twitter.com/PremierLake?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw"
        >Tweets by PremierLake</a
      >
      <script
        async
        src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js"
        charset="utf-8"
      ></script>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LR0Cn.jpg)][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LR0Cn.jpg)